# Having Freudian child parent problems with my objects. Need some pointers and/or Reference?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I think I have a basic question that is sort of hard to look up, I think.

Objective-C for Iphone.

I want to create two view controller instances that message and update an instance of a Model Class. How do you do this? I would prefer no using singletons. It's basically an "I really want to learn from you guys because this is awesome and I want to be awesome too!" question.

I would prefer we keep app delegate, singletons, nsnotification center out of the picture. App delegate specifically in that I dont think I wnat to have my data object created by app delegate, but I may have to.

The way, as I understand it, this works is sort of like this. Navigation Controller creates instance of FirstLevelViewController. My FirstLevelViewController creates instances of my SecondLevelViewControllers and then when told to pushes them onto the navcontroller stack.

I have my Model Instance being created by my firstlevelviewcontroller instance. Is that wrong? I think I need a reference to the instance passed to my secondlevelviewcontroller, but I'm having trouble because I can't figure out what the instance name of the firstlevelviewcontroller is (I think NavController instantiated it).

Help is so very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure hence not an answer but you should be able to access it via [super modelInstance]. If its only needed where you say yes you should stay away from singletons but you might get some benefit from using NSNotification or delegates though, just depends too much on what your doing though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the model stays the same object (it can be mutable but not deallocated within the lifetime of BOTH view controllers), one might use a separate variable in each view controller to point to the same model class, with each view controller not knowing about the other.  This is of course dependent on your application specific logic -- if one view controller 'knows about' the other than of course it makes sense to have the model be 'owned' but the independent one, and accessible to the dependent one via properties.  However this considered bad because it promotes code coupling and dependency, which is looked at as poor coding.  As to how both view controllers get the same model instance, typically it would be set (preferably in initialization) by whatever knows about them both, such as a higher level view controller, or if they are root view controllers, the app delegate.